# Does not find a parameter when ajax request

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to add data from the form to DB with AJAX request. The controller that calls the page on which the changes occur accepts the 'event' parameter

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/event")
public ModelAndView event(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session)
{
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    SimpleUser simpleUser = simpleUserService.findById((Integer) session.getAttribute("userId"));
    Profile profile = simpleUser.getProfile();
    modelAndView.addObject("nameOfEventOwner", profile.getName());
    modelAndView.addObject("surnameOfEventOwner", profile.getSecondName());

    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("event"));
    System.out.println(id);

    modelAndView.addObject("event", eventService.findById(id));
    modelAndView.setViewName("eventpage");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

On the page there is a form, the data from which I want to enter into the db (later dynamically on the page)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%--
Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
User: Yura
Date: 10.05.2017
Time: 15:30
To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" />"></script>
   <script>
    function call() {
        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        var rate = $("#rate").val();

        $.ajax({
            url : "/addcomment",
            method : 'GET',
            data : {
                comment : comment,
                rate : rate,
                idEvent: ${event.getId()},
                idAuthor: ${sessionScope.simpleUser.getId()}
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success : function(results){
                alert("add");
            }
        });
    };
</script>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    owner: ${nameOfEventOwner} ${surnameOfEventOwner}
    <br>${event.getNameOfEvent()} <pre> ${event.getDateOfEvent()}}</pre>
    <br> ${event.getDescription()}
    <br> ${event.getTag()}
    <br>
    <form>
        Commentary: <input type="text" id="comment" placeholder="text">
        Rating: <input type="text" id="rate" placeholder="rating">
        <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="call()">Add   commentary</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to pass these values to the controller via AJAX. But when I pass the values, my page is reload and I'm busted by the NumberFormatExseption error, because 'event' parameter is not initialized. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of the button to "button".

When the type is "submit", the action will try to submit the form reloading the page.

Using the "button" type, you just delegate the action to the `call()` function.

```
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="call()">Add   commentary</button>
```